# Vuetify v-radio what is the best CSS label margin value?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

Given a radio group

```
                      <v-flex xs-12 sm-3 md-3 lg-3>
                        <v-radio-group
                          row
                          v-model="honorificPrefix"
                          v-validate="'required'"
                          required
                          >
                          <v-radio class="radio" :label="$t('lang.views.contact.mrs')" :value="$t('lang.views.contact.mrs')"></v-radio>
                          <v-radio class="radio" :label="$t('lang.views.contact.mr')" :value="$t('lang.views.contact.mr')"></v-radio>
                        </v-radio-group>
                      </v-flex>
```

the output shows aa too large space between the icon and the label

[image: radio group]

how can I setup the CSS to manage the space between the icon and the label  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Can you provide codepen and point out the issue you want resolved? afaics you are using  `v-flex` `sm-3` which might be too narrow in the first place.

Comment: yes , you're right .. v-flex , it's quite uneasy to modify the Css margins-padding in the radio button... I did not changed the size but I set the radio buttons as a column...  ( btw , the issue I tried to resolved was to set less space between the icon and the label...)

Comment: Wait, lol. I didn't notice that `sm-3` et al can't work in the first place, it should be `sm3` (**no hyphen**, I see you are using it everywhere, does it work for you somehow? Am I missing something?). I understood what you are about to do, but I was just worried that you shouldn't do it, because you could break the guidelines.

Comment: But anyway, if you are about to narrow down the space between icon and the label, I guess you should put  `:ripple="false"` on your radio buttons (turns off the ripple effect so it doesn't overlap with the label), and then you can add `margin-left: -10px;` to `.radio.input-group label`.

Comment: thanks a lot for this feedback... did not know yet about :ripple...  great feedback !! you write it as an answer ... I'll vote for it ... very useful ...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to narrow down the space between icon and the label, you should put `:ripple="false"` on your radio buttons (turns off the ripple effect so it doesn't overlap with the label), and then you can add `margin-left: -10px;` to `.radio.input-group label`.